# How to avoid accessing builtin bash variables or deliberately clobber them

Tags: bash, built-in

I spent a little time today troubleshooting the following seemingly straightforward-looking script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -u

declare -a GROUPS=( "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" )
echo "${GROUPS[@]}"

exit 0
```

What comes out of `echo` is not what is actually in the declared array. It turns out that `GROUPS` is a builtin variable in `bash`, and `declare -a GROUPS` does not redefine this variable.

I'm curious if there is a `set` option or other approach people use to catch attempts to declare variables or functions that have the same name as a builtin? Or are there ways people have used to clobber/overwrite/extend values of variables or functions in `bash`, generally speaking?

Comment: Use lowercase names.

Comment: ^ That's the [POSIX guideline](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), too (fourth paragraph).

Comment: By convention, environment and shell builtin variables are all capitalized. So lowercase variable names should be preferred for your own variables.

Comment: [This unix.stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/339347) says: **To prevent your own variables from conflicting with these variables, it is a good practice to use lower_case variable names.**

Comment: A classic example of varname collision.